# What is the print format for atomic_long_t for printk in C

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

I am trying to print an atomic_long_t value but I am unable to find the correct format to use it so that it prints actual information. I have tried

```
struct zone *mzone;
atomic_long_t l; 
for_each_zone(mzone);
l=mzone ->vm_stat[NR_ACTIVE_ANON];
printk(KERN EMERG "NR_ACTIVE_ANON: %lu",l);
```

and

```
printk(KERN EMERG "NR_ACTIVE_ANON: %ld",l);
```

but all I get is 0 no matter what. I have also tried atomic_long_read, but it expects a struct pointer atomic_long_t.

Comment: If desperate, code could `unsigned char buf[sizeof l]; memcpy(buf, &l, sizeof l);` and then print the `buf[]`.  You would see the data  as a sea of bytes.  But perhaps that is the point of `atomic_long_t`, treat it as a sea of bytes rather than an integer.

Comment: @chux I'm pretty sure the point of atomic types is to get rid of using locks in multi-threaded environment

Comment: The usage of `atomic_long_t` is not the issue.  The post requests how to print its value.

Comment: @chux Maybe the `;` after `for_each_zone()` causes that issue with 0?.. Anyway, developers should stick to atomic API. And there is none special `printk` format for atomic variables. Otherwise we'd see it [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt).

Answer (score 1):

1. Pay attention to `;`  in the end of `for_each_zone()` line in your code. It's probably shouldn't be there.
2. You are right that you should use `atomic_long_read()`. Just give it a pointer it wants. There is no need to use some fancy `printk()` format for atomic types (and there is none). Here is an example:

   ```c
   #include <asm/atomic.h>

   ...

   atomic_long_t v = ATOMIC_LONG_INIT(0);

   atomic_long_set(&v, 123);
   pr_info("%ld\n", atomic_long_read(&v));
   ```

   This code prints `123`.

   Also, be sure to use atomic API for other operations. Because basically `atomic_long_t` type is a struct, defined like this:

   ```c
   typedef atomic_t atomic_long_t;

   typedef struct {
       long counter;
   } atomic64_t;
   ```

   And I'm pretty sure it was done exactly for that reason: to prevent user from using regular operations on that type, or casting it to some regular type.

   You can find a lot of documentation about atomic API around:

   - [LDD3, chapter 5](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch05.pdf) (see "Atomic Variables" section)
   - [Documentation/atomic_t.txt](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/atomic_t.txt)
   - [core-api/atomic_ops.html](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/core-api/atomic_ops.html)
   - [Atomic and pointer manipulation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/driver-api/basics.html)